# How do I know when I installed my distribution?

Tags: command-line, mageia

I use Mageia 5.1 64bit and I would like to know when I installed it ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you still have at least one rpm package which was never updated since installation:

```
rpm -qa --last | tail
```

Otherwise you could check the / filesystem creation time, e.g. for ext* FS:

```
tune2fs -l /dev/sdaX  | grep -i created
```

Replcae `sdaX` with your root partition.

Or you may have luck to find it *in* your oldest log files:

```
ls -lt /var/log/
```

You may compare several dates of all the different commands above and if some of them agree then there are good chances that this is your installation date.

Comment: But I always update my system, how do I know witch package never been updated ?

Comment: this is the output : https://pastebin.com/ARLECZAQ

Comment: The first and the 3rd gave me the same date  : Mar 4 2016
 thank you

Answer (score 0):

During the system install a `lost + found` will be created , check it with:

```
ls -ld /lost+found
```

Alternative answer from [here](https://translate.google.tn/translate?hl=en&sl=fr&u=http://www.tux-planet.fr/connaitre-la-date-dinstallation-dun-systeme-linux/&prev=search) , use the command:

```
ls -lct /etc | tail -1 | awk '{print $6, $7, $8}'
```

or

```
df / | awk '{print $1}' | grep dev | xargs tune2fs -l | grep create
```

or

```
dumpe2fs -h $(df | awk '/\/$/ {print $1}') | grep created
```

Comment: All these commands gave me the same date : Mar 4 2016
thank you